# liferay id generator accross the database

Tags: database, oracle, liferay, liferay-6.2

I have been given a task to migrate users from customers database to liferay portal.

I have already managed to find all the places I need to fill with data, to make a user functional (USER_, USERS_GROUPS, CONTACT_, LAYOUTSET, EXPANDOVALUE).

The only problem I have faced are the IDs. Liferay doesn't use a sequence to generate them (at least I haven't found one), but appears to generate them from the code. What's even more concerning, It looks like all the IDs (UserID, GroupId, RowID, etc) need to be unique not only in scope of a table, but whole database.

I need to find a way to get the last used ID in database and a way to set last ID used by my script, so that Liferay doesn't use it again.

I don't have access to an application server, just the database, that's why I can't use the API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to ask, why do you have no access to the application server? Changing things in the database is like repairing a modern car without tools and manual. It is possible to get all things right - but it is possible as well to screw all things up, if you forget anything that the API is usually thinking off.

That having said:
The counter ID is saved in the `COUNTER` table in the row with name `com.liferay.counter.model.Counter`. It is incremented by the value of the property `counter.increment` (usually 100). Check the class `CounterFinderImpl` to see how Liferay is using it.

Ensure that the server is stopped before modifying anything in the database - as Liferay is caching many things, especially the current counter value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tobias! I have already located the Counter table, but as the value stored in it didn't exactly match the values I saw in tables, I wasn't really sure if it's the right track.

The case of access to an app server is quite political (in a business way) and all that I know is that I have to do it only via database.